# Textbox not updating after thread abort

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a thread which is executing a sub and within a sub I am updating the textbox during a "Do while" loop is in progress. I then created a cancel button to abort the thread.

When the button is clicked then the thread is aborted but the textbox (Status_Txtbox.Text) doesn't get updated with the message "Parsing is terminated". I tried to do the debug and I see the code is executed perfectly and if condition for thread.isalive satisfies but not sure why the textbox doesn't get updated with the message.

Any idea how to update the textbox once thread is aborted ?

> ```
> Dim thrd1 As Thread
> Private Sub Parse_Btn_2G_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Parse_Btn_2G.Click
>     Parse_Btn_2G.IsEnabled = False
>     Scan_Btn_2G.IsEnabled = False
>     cancel_Btn_2G.IsEnabled = True
>     Dim start As DateTime = DateTime.Now
>     Dim elapsedtime As Double
>     Dim action As Action
>     thrd1 = New Thread(Sub()
>                            ButtonClickWork.DoWork()
>                            action = Sub()
>                                         Status_Txtbox.Text = "Parsing Data, Please wait..."
>                                     End Sub
>                            Me.Dispatcher.Invoke(action)
>                        End Sub)
>     thrd1.Start()
>     elapsedtime = (DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds) / 60
>     elapsedtime = Math.Round(elapsedtime, 2)
>     Status_Txtbox.Text = " Managed Objects in XML, total time elapsed is" & elapsedtime
> End Sub
> ```

```
  Private Sub Cancel_Btn_2G_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles cancel_Btn_2G.Click
    Try
        If cancel_Btn_2G.IsEnabled = True Then
            If MsgBox("Do you really want to exit Parsing?", vbYesNo) = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
                Parse_Btn_2G.IsEnabled = True
                Scan_Btn_2G.IsEnabled = True
                cancel_Btn_2G.IsEnabled = False
                thrd1.Abort()
                thrd1.Join()
                If thrd1.IsAlive = False Then
                    Status_Txtbox.Text = "Parsing is terminated"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As ThreadAbortException
        Status_Txtbox.Text = "Parsing is terminated"
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: I would guess that the `IsAlive` property of the `Thread` doesn't change quickly enough for it to be `False` when that code is executed normally. By breaking in the debugger, you probably give it enough time to change and so it works as you expect in that case. Try adding a call to `Join` after `Abort` and that should, I believe, wait until the abortion is complete. That said, aborting a thread like that not recommended so you should avoid it if at all possible. If you are going to use it, you should be catching the `ThreadAbortException` is causes in that other thread.

Comment: Thanks jmcil, I tried adding thrd1.join in "Cancel_btn_Click" Sub but it doesn't make any difference, I have updated the code for your reference. Also, can you please advise if I have used threadabortexception correctly.

Comment: The `ThreadAbortException` should be caught in the thread that is being aborted. That's where you perform appropriate cleanup and allow the thread to exit cleanly, rather than effectively crashing it. You should read the documentation for the `Thread.Abort` method, Ideally, you would have already read it, before trying to use it.